# Does async function need to have await inside it even if there is await on the caller of the function?

Tags: javascript

i have a confusion on how async/await works in JS.
i know await will let the exceution to wait until the awaited function is done

but in this example:

```
async function myAsyncFunction() {
  console.log("Inside async function");
  await new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
    // "Producing Code" (May take some time)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('setTimeout');
      myResolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
  console.log("Async function resumed");
}

async function callerFunction() {
  console.log("Before calling async function");
  await myAsyncFunction();
  console.log("After calling async function");
}

callerFunction();
```

its not clear to me why MyAsyncFunction need a promise inside of it for the callerFunction to wait for myAsyncFunction

why this solution doesn't let the excecution wait:

```
async function myAsyncFunction() {
  console.log("Inside async function");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('setTimeout');
    }, 3000);
  console.log("Async function resumed");
}

async function callerFunction() {
  console.log("Before calling async function");
  await myAsyncFunction();
  console.log("After calling async function");
}

callerFunction();
```

Comment: *"why this solution doesn't let the excecution wait"* - Because within `myAsyncFunction` no `Promise` is being awaited.  In the second example there's no logic which would cause the `setTimeout` operation to be awaited.  It creates the timeout and immediately returns.

Comment: because setTimeout is asynchronous.... so it is set and forget and the code moves on.

Comment: @David adding async keyword to a function wraps it implicilty with promise right? so if myAsyncFunction is wrapped with a hidden promise why the callerFunction doesn't wait for the setTimeout to finish. or im missing something here?

Comment: @SaifOs: What you're missing here is that *within* the `myAsyncFunction` nothing in the second example is being awaited.  Any Promise that you want to await would need to be awaited.  Just calling `await` at the top-level is not going to instruct the code to await anything that may possibly be wrapped in a Promise everywhere in the code.  (And `setTimeout` isn't even Promise-based, so it couldn't be directly awaited even if that was how awaiting worked.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you mark a function as `async`:

- It returns a promise which resolves to whatever the function returns.
- It begins to support the `await` keyword.

Simply returning a promise is rarely useful. That is a necessary consequence of supporting `await`.

---

`await` sends the function is belongs to to sleep until the promise on the right hand side of the `await` has resolved.

In the second example:

> ```
> async function myAsyncFunction() {
>   console.log("Inside async function");
>     setTimeout(() => {
>       console.log('setTimeout');
>     }, 3000);
>   console.log("Async function resumed");
> }
> ```

`myAsyncFunction`:

1. Logs *Inside async function*
2. Passes a callback to `setTimeout`
3. Logs *Async function resumed*

It returns a promise that resolves as `undefined` (since it is `async` and there is no return statement).

At some point in the future the timeout triggers the callback function.

**At no point does it pause**, because there is no `await` statement (so the log at step 3 above is misleading).